# Stretch layout height 100% after scrollbars

Tags: css

I have a three-column, fixed header/footer and three-column content layout, where left and right DIVs don't stretch to 100% height when the middle DIV overflows..

Any suggestion? Also, what do you think as far layout CSS and it's cross-browser compatibility and overall CSS usage?

Cheers,
David

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsTYJ/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Sample Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html 
            {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body 
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            } 
            #container-main
            {      
                background: #888888;   
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font: 1.5em "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;    
                height: 100%;               
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 768px;
            }    
            #container-left, #container-middle, #container-right
            {            
                float: left;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;                  
                min-height: 100%;
            }  
            #container-left
            {            
                background: #777777;
                width: 25%;
            } 
            #container-middle
            {            
                background: #999999;
                width: 60%;
            } 
            #container-right
            {            
                background: #777777;
                width: 15%;
            } 
            #container-header 
            { 
                background: #eee; 
                border: 0px solid #666; 
                height: 60px; 
                left: 0; 
                position: fixed; 
                width: 100%; 
                top: 0;  
                padding: 0;                      
            }
            #header-left, #header-middle, #header-right 
            { 
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 60px; 
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0;
                float: left;                         
            }  
            #header-left
            {  
                background: #999999;
                width: 25%;             
            }  
            #header-middle
            {  
                background: #888888;
                width: 60%;             
            } 
            #header-right
            {  
                background: #999999;
                width: 15%;             
            }                              
            #container-content 
            { 
                margin: 0; 
                overflow: auto; 
                padding: 50px 0 50px 0; 
                width: 100%; 
            }
            #content
            {
            }
            #container-footer 
            { 
                background:#eee; 
                border: 0px solid #666; 
                bottom:0; 
                height:60px; 
                left:0; 
                position:fixed; 
                width:100%; 
            }
            #footer-left, #footer-middle, #footer-right 
            { 
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 60px; 
                margin: 0; 
                float: left;                         
            }  
            #footer-left
            {  
                background: #999999;
                width: 25%;             
            }  
            #footer-middle
            {  
                background: #888888;
                width: 60%;             
            } 
            #footer-right
            {  
                background: #999999;
                width: 15%;             
            }                                                              
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container-main">
            <div id="container-left">            
                Content 1
            </div>
            <div id="container-middle">
                <div id="container-header">
                    <div id="header-left">
                        Header Left
                    </div>
                    <div id="header-middle">
                        Header Middle
                    </div>
                    <div id="header-right">
                        Header Right
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="container-content">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="container-footer">
                    <div id="footer-left">
                        Footer Left
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-middle">
                        Footer Middle
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-right">
                        Footer Right
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container-right">
                Content 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jsFiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Fiddle Here:- http://jsfiddle.net/z837M/

Change i did was not to wrap the content with the background and you can use background-size is you are planning to place any image later and you can use 100% or cover as its value. Make the position Fixed and Z-Index :-1

### CSS

```
#container-main
            {      
                background: #888888;   
                -webkit-background-size: 100%;
                -moz-background-size: 100%;
                -o-background-size: 100%;
                background-size: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font: 1.5em "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;    
                height: auto;               
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
               position:fixed;
               z-index:-1;
            }
```

### Html

```
  <div id="container-left">            
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div id="container-middle">
        <div id="container-header">
            <div id="header-left">
                Header Left
            </div>
            <div id="header-middle">
                Header Middle
            </div>
            <div id="header-right">
                Header Right
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container-content">
            <div id="content">

                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                    
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container-footer">
            <div id="footer-left">
                Footer Left
            </div>
            <div id="footer-middle">
                Footer Middle
            </div>
            <div id="footer-right">
                Footer Right
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container-right">
        Content 3
    </div>
```

### UPDATE

Use table display to have the columns take full height. Since you have some fixed elements it doesn't matter where they reside. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nBzc/)

#### CSS

```
    div.column {
        display:table-cell;
    }
    div.section {
        display:table-row;
    }
```

#### HTML

```
  <div id="container-wrapper" class="section">
        <div id="container-left" class="column">
            <div class="container-content">Content 1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="container-middle" class="column">
            <div class="container-content">
                <div id="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container-right" class="column">Content 3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add more content and see copy paste more <p> content that you have... And also probably the background color as #777777

Comment: @PSCoder's answer looks good to me, including the scroll bar.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YsAHX/ This sample has to scroll :), added more content and moved font specification to body...

Comment: I see that #content-left and #content-righ still don't stretch 100%. Am I missing something? I updated #content-main background color and you can see what I mean..

Comment: For that wrap your containers unser a wrapper div so that they all float inside a positioned div.. http://jsfiddle.net/angYD/ . Is this what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I'm trying to have #content-left, #cotaniner-middle and #content-right to stretch 100% height. What's happening right now is that, if #container-middle overflows, which is normal, other two are staying at their initial height. Try changing background color of #container-main and you'll see..

Comment: I got what you are saying... Let me check if i can find out. Fixed header could be one culprit.

Comment: @Ostati- Have a look at the update now and the fiddle. i checked in IE, FF and CHrome placing this as an html and seems like this is what you are looking for. Have a look.

Comment: If you remove <p> tags so that the overflow does not happen, content does not stretch to 100% height.. Looks like we're in the dead-end zone.

Comment: The problem now is that your divs are having percentage heights or auto. So it will Expand/shrink based on the availability/unavailability of enough content. And what make the layout look weird is the fixed Footer which will always remain at the bottom and remaining space will be filled by the background.